# Can i write this condition in better way?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I need to check if variable has some value or null then use variable value otherwise take default value. I have used below condition, how can i write it in better way?

```
const newVal = val === null ? null : val || defaultVal;
```

Comment: `var val = val || defaultVal;` assuming you are ok with val being defaultVal if val ===0

Comment: no, no, no, because that would overwrite val if val was null ... and you wouldn't use that in a var declaration anyway!

Comment: please add the possible values for `val` and for `defaultVal`, because it defines the check and the final result.

Comment: btw, zero is *some value*, but falsy.

Comment: let me disect the code ... if val is null, keep it as null, otherwise if it's falsey, set it to defaultVal, otherwise leave it alone

Comment: @mplungjan if use that way in that case if val has null it will take default value, but i want to to assign null if val is null instead of default value

Comment: @JaromandaX exactly that is what i want to do.

Comment: Then what you have looks correct

Comment: the way you got it is the most concise

Comment: so, the code does exactly what you need, you just want to know if there's a better way - there is no better way I can think of

Comment: well, damn, there is a (slightly) more readable solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a conditional statement with two checks for returning `val`, otherwise return `defaultVal`.

```js
var val = null,
    defaultVal = 'foo',
    newVal = val || val === null ? val : defaultVal;
    
console.log(newVal);
```

Comment: so in one line `val || val === null ? val : defaultVal` - that is actually more readable!

Answer (score 3):

If by *better* you mean *more readable*, here is how your condition behaves:

```js
if (val) {
  return val;
} else if (val === null) {
  return null;
} else {
  return defaultVal;
}
```

Comment: is if else better than turnery operator?

Comment: @eramit2010 better in this case is that some may consider this more readable.

Comment: You don't need `else if`: `if (val || val === null)` should be sufficient

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to a `ternary`, you can write is as: `val || val === null ? val : defaultValue`

```js
const getVal = (val, defaultValue = 0) => val || val === null ? val : defaultValue;

const val1 = null;
const val2 = 2599;
const val3 = undefined;
const val4 = 0;

console.log(
  getVal(val1),    // null
  getVal(val2),    // 2599
  getVal(val3, 5), // 5
  getVal(val4)     // 0
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const newVal = (function(v, defValue){return v||(v===null?null:defValue)})("desiredValue", "defValue");
```

in your sample:

```
const newVal = (function(v, dfV){return v||(v===null?null:dfV)})(val, defaultVal);
```

---

you can remove the function and use the condition singly:

```
 const newVal = val||(val===null?null:defaultVal);
```